# Remove unused js and css in Next js - performance optimization

Tags: web, bootstrap-5, next.js13, web-development-server, google-pagespeed

I am using the bootstrap and jQuery in my next js website, pages I used to create from strapi cms, static site generation, I am facing some performance issue, shows like web core vital failed, remove the unused CSS and js , can anyone help me with this?

I have tried purge css with my source, but it is not working , i am facing import errors
i am targeting to remove the unused css and JS from my next js source